# how to make a carousel in the center and fit 3/4 of the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

im working with HTML and right now i just added a carousel item to my html project, my question is how can you display the carousel in the middle of the page since it appears at the left side.

www.littlebossworld.com

Comment: i need a css code to input on my carousel element (this is avada theme)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What's your HTML code ?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you have to use `!important` attribute because your carousel plugin is adding inline styles (maybe there is a setup where you can change this?).

"hard" css:

```
.fusion-carousel .fusion-carousel-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Comment: i add your code here CSS Class
Add a class to the wrapping HTML element.

But its not working

Answer (score 0):

[this shows the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKvYV.jpg)

This Code Help for you

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .corosolstylelog {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hight = $(window).height();
            var hightforcourosol = ($(window).height() / 4) * 3;
            var width = ($(window).width() / 2);

            $('.carousel-inner img').css("height", hightforcourosol);
            $('.carousel-inner a img').css("height", hightforcourosol);
            $('.carousel-inner img').css("width", width);
            $('.carousel-inner a img').css("width", width);
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        Left Side 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 corosolstylelog">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="Image/Carousel/a.jpg" alt="Chania">

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chania</h3>
                        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image/Carousel/b.jpg" alt="Chania">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chania</h3>
                        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image/Carousel/c.jpg" alt="Flower">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Flowers</h3>
                        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
       Right Side
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```